# Char array in c++ cannot be erased | Dump still possible using Process Hacker

Tags: c++

I want to implement secure solution, which would prevent dumping password from memory after it usage. I tried few solutions, but even when i used all of them, i still can dump my password which should be erased from memory. My code:

```
char str[49] = "This is a string literal. See the double quotes?";

//        cout << "Secret variable is: " << str << " with length: " << strlen(str) << endl;

cleanse(str, sizeof(str));
memset(str, 0, sizeof(str));
SecureZeroMemory(str, sizeof(str));
OPENSSL_cleanse(str, sizeof(str));
```

Even after using all of those functions at one time - in memory dump my secret variable appear

My compile params:

```
-s -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -fuse-ld=lld -Wl,--gc-sections -fstack-protector
```

[image]

That's how i dumping memory using Process Hacker, then i'm using `strings` to extract all strings from memory and here it is:
[image]

Value which should never appear here, what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: `"This is a string literal ..."` That's an ironic comment?

Comment: You  may have 2 copies. [Assigning a string literal to a char array, how is the string literal copied onto the stack?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16153339)

Comment: @john it's not my real password of course :D it's taken from one website because i though that the problem is usage of std::string, but after i replaced to char[] the problem still exists

Comment: @JohnnyMopp so, how should i assign my secret variable to char array? Using memcpy?

Comment: What happens if you modify the program to get the string from the user from stdin, removing the string literal completely?

Comment: @JohnnyMopp i don't get what you mean, could you explain it more?

Comment: Change `char str[49] = "This is a string literal. See the double quotes?";` to `char str[49]; fgets(str, sizeof(str), stdin);` And enter the text on the command line.

Comment: Ahh, you mean that, but i don't know if that make any sense, because i want to store that password in binary, user shouldn't enter anything

Comment: @JohnnyMopp forgot to ping

Comment: That's a whole other issue. You can load an exe into notepad and see the text in the data section so your concept is not secure. This is outside my area of expertise. A google search for "c++ store password in exe" came up with a few results.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245947/discussion-between-kaspek-and-johnny-mopp).

Answer (score 1):

In `C++`, string literals have type `const char[N]`, where `N` is the size of the string including the terminating null character. The effect of your line

```
char str[49] = "This is a string literal. See the double quotes?";
```

is to copy the string literal into the `str` array at program startup. This creates a *copy* of your password in the `str` array; the original string literal remains unchanged. And it is this original string literal that is found by the `strings` app.

To get round this, you could initialise the `str` array at runtime, from user input. But if you use a library routine like `fgets` to do this, you have no control over what it does; for all I know, it might save a copy of the input line somewhere internally. So if `strings` *still* finds your password somewhere in memory, you will have to implement your own character input handling.

---

By the way, you are creating problems for yourself by specifying the size of the `str` array; if the string length ever changes, your code will fail to compile (or worse). Simpler and better is

```
char str[] = "This is a string literal. See the double quotes?";
```

which has the same effect.

Comment: So maybe i asked wrong about it, what is best solution (like string, char array etc) to store that kind of things like private keys, passwords

Answer (score 0):

The process needs to be able to initialize that string when the function is called. Even if the value stored on the stack is cleared, it will still remain present in binary that was loaded. It is very important that you understand:

**No matter what we add in the code, it won't be enough to stop a professional cybersecurity engineer from finding a password stored or generated within a binary without the addition of a separate key.**

We zero the memory of a password because it did not exist prior to the start of the program so we can minimize the time it is held in memory. There is no safe way to store a password in the binary, but we can do some tricks to make it harder to find. We can **pretend** to have security by storing an encoded version of the password. However, it will still be difficult to store it in a way that prevents the compiler from optimizing the password back into its plain text form.

Ideally the password (or private key) would only be stored on a trusted system. This binary would be passed to untrusted systems which must send requests to the trusted system. The trusted system then acts on their behalf while ignoring malicious or malformed requests.

**Side Note:** This question may be the result of the [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/). Why are you attempting to store the password? What do you actually want to do? There may be a simpler answer to your problem which does not require storing the password in a binary.

Comment: Well, but even if i obfuscated strings using Code Virtualizer, and `strings` from binary doesnt show that secret string, if i do dump from memory it appears in memory dump